# How to set up audio multicast on Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, media-server

I have Raspberry Pi 3.

I would like to setup an audio multicast server on the Raspberry Pi (i.e.
I would like the rendezvous point to be on the Raspberry Pi).

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to multicast audio streams to or from the Pi, or indeed handle multiple network audio streams generally in Linux, I suggest you have a look at PulseAudio, which supports receiving and broadcasting multicast RTP audio streams:

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index39h3

See module-rtp-send and module-rtp-rcv